# Change root view controller using HERO transition

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I have this code....

```
 UIView.transition(with: window!, duration: 0.3, options: **animation**, animations: {
            window!.rootViewController = rootVC
        }, completion: nil
```

Is it possible put Hero transition replacing "animation" var?

Comment: I would have a look into the docs: [https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero/wiki/Usage-Guide](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero/wiki/Usage-Guide)

Comment: i read the documentation yet but my question is about to...if is possible that hero transition works with "window.rootViewController" like .crossDisolve or Flip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example:

```
   let current = window.rootViewController!
   let transition = HeroTransition()
   // Collapse vertically in dismissal, over 1 second.
   current.view.hero.modifiers = [.scale(x: 1, y: 0.1, z: 1), .duration(1), .fade]
   // Rotate in, over 2 seconds.
   replacement.view.hero.modifiers = [.rotate(z:1.6), .duration(2), .fade]

   transition.transition(from: current, to: replacement, in: window) { (finished) in
      window.rootViewController = replacement
                
   }
```